# Is data recovery from damaged CD-ROM possible?

Tags: data-recovery, compact-disc

I have a totally unscratched 700 MB CD-ROM that always been in its case, but it was on the top of the stack and took some sunlight (from a close window) during months (if not years).

The CD looks like new but the data can't be read. I kept it for years (now in a dark closet) and tested it with all CD/DVD drives I owned (many brands, LG, Asus, Samsung...). None could read the data (after many minutes, Windows tells to insert a CD in the drive as if the CD wasn’t there). Tested it with XP, Vista and 7 with no luck.

I'm sure ultra expensive data recovery services could recover some (if not all) of its data (CD-R is half full). Do I have alternatives? I saw much software who claims that they can recover lost data like this but I'm skeptical.

Anyone have successfully recovered data from a (sunlight) damaged CD-R? If so, how?

Comment: It may well be damaged beyond recovery, except perhaps at a price you couldn't pay. Since CD-Rs use photosensitive dyes to record information, the sunlight could very well have wiped all the data clean. A government forensics lab might be able to retrieve a disk in that state, but your average commercial shop can't.

Comment: BTW only the front of the disc (NOT the surface beign writed to) was exposed to sunlight.

Comment: If you lived back in the before-times and left video tapes, cassette tapes, or records on the dash of a car, you may have seen them melted in the sun.  CDs and DVDs can too.  The sun is an amazing thing.

Comment: Yeah I know I saw melted VHS back in the days, but now we are talking of a CD left inside on a shelf with some indirect sunlight from a window with curtains... My CD look like new: not deformed, "just" unreadable.

Comment: If your CR-R is “years” old it is almost certainly unrecoverable. Heat and ultraviolet light can destroy CD-R data in days, but the dyes used in CD-Rs (especially old ones) are chemically unstable and will degrade in years no matter how they are stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try safecopy http://safecopy.sourceforge.net/ - seems to exist for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Try Linux.

At the very least, you might be able to `dd` data off the disc. However, there are probably a few LiveCD distros built for data recovery, and they'll probably have better tools. Of course, if you choose to go with a LiveCD Linux, you're going to either need a second CD drive, or to boot off a thumb-drive.

Comment: I always have 2 DVD-Writers on my PCs. I might try that...